# Disable surround sound with openAL

Tags: audio, openal, lwjgl

I'm french so sorry for my english.

I'm currently making a splitscreen 2D game with LWJGL.
I'm using the openAL API which is given with LWJGL. Everything seems to works perfectly. Well, too perfectly to be honest : because I'm making a splitscreen game and because I can't have 2 listener sharing the same context, I want to get rid of the left/right panning.

Sound attenuation work well. I change the position of sound depending on the closest player.
The listener doesn't change, always at (0,0,0). The sound position is (soundPosition - closestPlayerPosition).

So how do I get rid of the surround thing ? I want to keep sound attenuation over distance, of course.
I could simply put the sound on the Z-axis depending on the distance but this seem a bit silly (I have to compute the distance every time I have to update a sound position).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate the sound's position (soundPosition - closestPlayerPosition) take the length of the vector returned by that and then put that sound directly down the z axis that distance away from the player.

Example:

soundPosition = (1.4,0,1.4)
closestPlayerPosition = (0,0,0)

soundDirection = soundPosition - closestPlayerPosition = (1.4,0,1.4)

soundDistance = soundDirection.Length()

And finally, the final position of your sound:

finalSoundPosition = (0,0,soundDistance) = (0,0,2)

Edit: I didn't notice you already suggested this. To be honest I think this is fine, and its the only way to solve your problem beyond rewriting stuff internal to openAL

Comment: I'm pretty proud of this... :D

Comment: I have to compute distance using a square root. If I use a square root, I could as well simply change the gain with this value. Seems like a bogus way of using a library which already do this :/

But well, If that's the only way to solve this... I'm going to use the |x1-x2|+|y1-y2| formulae because I'm already using it. Thanks !

Comment: Theres a difference between gain and distance though - different frequencies of sound attenuate at different rates over distance. The maths is far more complicated than changing the gain

Comment: I had to use the Y axis instead of the Z axis, because the Y axis is upward. Just to let you know. It work perfectly now !